# Returning a subclass from its base class in swift

Tags: inheritance, swift

I am trying to allow a method in a super class to return an instance of the subclass so that I can use method chaining with methods across both the parent and the child.

However, I am getting the error "BaseClass does not have a member named someOtherChainableMethod" when I attempt to chain the methods. Here is my code:

```
class BaseClass {
    func someChainableMethod() -> BaseClass {
        return self
    }
}

class ChildClass: BaseClass {
    func someOtherChainableMethod() -> ChildClass {
        return self
    }
}

let childClass = ChildClass

childClass.someChainableMethod().someOtherChainableMethoid()
```

The issue seems to be that the 'return self' in the parent chain-able method is returning an instance with type `BaseClass` rather than `ChildClass`.

I have also tried this with generics and failed, this is what I tried:

```
class BaseClass<T> {
    func someChainableMethod() -> T {
        return self
    }
}

class ChildClass: BaseClass<ChildClass> {
    func someOtherChainableMethod() -> ChildClass {
        return self
    }
}

let childClass = ChildClass

childClass.someChainableMethod().someOtherChainableMethoid()
```

In this case the error from the `BaseClass` `someChainableMethod` method, is "BaseClass is not convertible to T".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code works if you change the return type of the methods to `Self`:

```
class BaseClass {
    func someChainableMethod() -> Self {
        return self
    }
}

class ChildClass: BaseClass {
    func someOtherChainableMethod() -> Self {
        return self
    }
}

let childClass = ChildClass()
let foo = childClass.someChainableMethod().someOtherChainableMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `someOtherChaingableMethod` in your base class and left a empty implementation.

Comment: The problem is that the someOtherChaingableMethod method is actually specific to ChildClass. There are multiple child classes with specific methods and I don't want to pollute my base class with them.

Comment: Or you can extract your chain methods to a protocol, let all class implement the protocol and response the protocol in your chain method.

Comment: You cannot achieve this through inheritance, hence base class does not know the methods of child class. Pollute all chain method to your base class, you can also have polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know that childClass is an instance of ChildClass, you can do

```
(childClass.someChainableMethod() as ChildClass).someOtherChainableMethoid()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply override the base class someChainableMethod

```
class BaseClass {
    func someChainableMethod() -> Self{
        return self
    }
}

class ChildClass: BaseClass {
    override func someChainableMethod() -> Self {
        return self
    }
    func A(){

    }
}

var objChild = ChildClass()
objChild.someChainableMethod()
```