# superclass methods to return subclass type in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mobile

I have this code:

```
class Dark: NSObject {
  class var className: String {
    return NSStringFromClass(self)!.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
  }

  var success = 0

  class func devour<T: Dark>(params: Int) -> T {
    var s = T()
    return assign(s, params: params)
  }

  class func assign<T: Dark>(item: T, params: Int) -> T{
    if item.dynamicType === self {
      item.success = params
    }
    return item
  }
}

class Black: Dark {
}

class Violet: Dark {
}

Black.className // returns "Black"
Violet.className // returns "Violet"
```

The problem occurs when I do this:

```
var ret = Black.devour(5)
ret.success //returns 0 which I expect to be 5

ret.self // returns {Dark success 0} which I expect to be {Black success 0}
```

The problem here is that when the subclass uses the inherited method devour, it returns an object of type `Dark`. I want to be able to return the subclass type and not the superclass type when calling devour. Example when I do:

```
var ret = Black.devour(5)
```

The class of ret should be of class `Black` and not of class `Dark`.

I hope someone can help me on this. Im really out of ideas. Thanks!
I want to avoid chaining and I consider it last resort.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Error log please.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296938/returning-a-subclass-from-its-base-class-in-swift

Comment: hi @RobinEllerkmann: The problem here is that when the subclass uses the inherited method devour, it returns an object of type Dark. I want to be able to return the subclass type and not the superclass type when calling devour

Answer (score 8):

It turns out I was able to do a work around; Thanks to the answer to this question: [Cast to typeof(self)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271208/cast-to-typeofself).

All I need to do is create a method which returns an object of type Self.

first, I created a class that creates an instance of the base class and return it as an instance of AnyObject.

```
    class func createDark() -> AnyObject {
          var black = Black()
          return black
    }
```

When I return an instance of `Black` it automatically casts it into AnyObject since it was the specified return type of the method (I honestly just figured this out and this saved me).

Then I created a helper method that calls `createDark()` and assigns properties/attributes to the instance:

```
    class func prepare<T: Dark>(params: Int) -> T{
        var dark = createDark() as T
        dark.assign(params)
        return dark
    }
```

I used generic type which is of `Dark` type or its subclass as a return type.

Then I did this:

```
    class func devour(params: Int) -> Self {
        return prepare(params)
    }
```

by specifying `Self` as return type, It automatically casts it to type of self which can be of `Dark` type or any class that inherits it.

My final code looks like this:

```
class Dark: NSObject {
    var success = 0

    func assign(params: Int) {
        if self.dynamicType === self { // I dont really have to do this anymore
            self.success = params
        }
    }

    class var className: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self)!.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
    }

    class func createDark() -> AnyObject {
        var black = Black()
        return black
    }

    class func prepare<T: Dark>(params: Int) -> T {
        var dark = createDark() as T
        dark.assign(params)
        return dark
    }

    class func devour(params: Int) -> Self {
        return prepare(params)
    }


}
```

to check if it solved the problem:

```
var ret = Black.devour(5)
ret.success //now returns 5 as expected

ret.self // now returns {Black success 0} as expected
```

works as expected!

Comment: What's the point if you have to write Black() explicitly in your superclass? What if I want to do the same with Violet, or some future subclass that doesn't exist yet?